# c# - How to get checked node value from Treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a Treeview with checkboxes when I click the parent node checkbox that child node will also be checked

I want to get the checked child node value

In the below code I got all the checked values even parent node value

But I don't want that parent node.

```
  protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
            {
                string checkedValue = node.Text.ToString();
                activityData = new ActivityData { ActivityName = checkedValue };
                listActivity.Add(activityData);
                Session["listActivity"] = listActivity;
            }
         }
    }
```

[image]

In the above image I don't want to get HR Activity(Parent node)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code. The main parent node does not have a parent.

You only need to set the session variable at the end of the foreach

Keep in mind that accesing or assigning session variables means that a deserialization/serialization of the object is happening

Also I dont know if maybe you need to clear or initialize the **listActivity** before the **foreach**. You can do this either with

```
listActivity = new List<ActivityData>() ;
```

or

```
listActivity.Clear();
```

Here is the code

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
        {
            //The main parent node does not have a parent
            if(node.Parent != null)
            {
                string checkedValue = node.Text.ToString();
                activityData = new ActivityData { ActivityName = checkedValue };
                listActivity.Add(activityData);
            }
        }

        //stablish the session variable only when the foreach has finished
        Session["listActivity"] = listActivity;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a property of a treeview node called Level, so you could skip nodes with a level of 0, course that will break down if you nest a level deeper.

If you know which parent node it is, then iterate through it's children and test for checked.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
            {
                if (node.Level > 0)
                {
                  string checkedValue = node.Text.ToString();
                  activityData = new ActivityData { ActivityName = checkedValue };
                  listActivity.Add(activityData);
                  Session["listActivity"] = listActivity;
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you please share sample code for the same.

Comment: I suppose I could put a bit of effort in, yes